# How to resolve or ignore Resharper error "Cannot resolve symbol" for Custom control Property

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, resharper

I'm using VS 2017 with Resharper Ultimate 2018.1.1

In my Xamarin.Forms project I have a content page with a custom BindableProperty declared in code behind.

XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyApp.Views.InitPage"
         x:Name="ctrl"
         InitializationStep="{Binding InitProgressStep}" >
```

C# code behind

```
public static readonly BindableProperty InitializationStepProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("InitializationStep", typeof(int), typeof(InitPage), 0);

public int InitializationStep
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(InitializationStepProperty); }
    set { SetValue(InitializationStepProperty, value); }
}
```

This compiles and works just fine.
The only issue is, that resharper keeps complaining, that it cannot found the property "InitializationStep" in the class "ContentPage", which is true, but Resparper should look in the InitPage-class instead.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this error? Or at least store in the resharper settings file to ignore this (because our build system is failing because of that error)

Comment: If you ask me the proper thing to do which will probably also fix this issue is creating an inheritance of the `ContentPage` and add it there.

Comment: Same Problem here. Do you have any solution so far?